# How can I check whether the location declared by a twitter's user exists?

Tags: java, twitter, lucene, geolocation, information-retrieval

I'm doing a twitter crawler and I have built a search engine on top of it using Lucene. Since many users submit locations that don't exist (e.g. "in my kitchen", "wonderland", "from LA to Paris"...), I think I should check which users to index depending on their location, in orer to make them reachable further with a location-search. I retrieve users by sampling english tweets (using TwitterStream.sample("en")).

My first idea was to download from some web sites all cities in the world and check if there was a match. However, there's a problem with this approach: It's difficult to find a document which contains all cities in the world spelled in all possible languages. The user, indeed, could either submit the name of his city (or country) in english, or in his own language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use geocoding [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), [yandex maps](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/About-docpage/).

> I'm facing the fact that the first link tells google API look for
>   cities in USA by default. So...if a user says he's in "Paris", google
>   API will response me NO_REPONSE

[Red Light District](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Red%20Light%20District)

> I have read the first link with much attention and the second link
>   with less attention, because the latter seems to be useful just for
>   javascript application (I'm doing all in java).

No. It is not correct. You can get information by a HTTP request, refer [HTTP request parameters](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/).

A small code snippet for [yandex maps](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/About-docpage/) using [apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/)

```
private void request(String geocode) throws IOException {
        HttpResponse response = Request.Post(SEARCH_URL).version(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
                .bodyForm(createForm(geocode).build(), Charsets.UTF_8).useExpectContinue()
                .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILS)
                .socketTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILS)
                .execute().returnResponse();

        assertStatus(response, geocode);
        getCoordinatesFromResponse(response, geocode);
    }

    private Form createForm(String geocode) {
        return Form.form().add("format", "json").add("results", "1").add("geocode", geocode);
    }

    private void assertStatus(HttpResponse response, String requestString) {
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() >= ERROR_STATUS_MIN) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format(
                    "Error sending request '%s' to the map service, server response: %s",
                    requestString, response));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have read the first link with much attention and the second link with less attention, because the latter seems to be useful just for javascript application (I'm doing all in java). I'm facing the fact that the first link tells google API look for cities in USA by default. So...if a user says he's in "Paris", google API will response me NO_REPONSE. Moroever, if he writes all his tweets in english, how can I get whether Paris exists? I have voted up your answer, by the way

Comment: @UtenteStack Thanks for vote up, I update my answer.

Comment: thanks, is it necessary to run tomcat to use google api?

Comment: I can't install the library from maven center repository. could you link me any guide or any site where I can learn, please? I have been trying for hours...I found this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html, but It doesn't work and I don't understand

Comment: @UtenteStack Which library do you want to install? Which IDE do you use? Which project structure do you have?

Comment: I use eclipse. I have all java sources in the default package (no modular structure, unfortunately). I'd like to install google-maps-services-0.1.10. I have installed it this night, following this procedure: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/, but I don't understand why I did the first step, because the library google-maps-services-0.1.10 does exist in maven center repository. I thought it would have been sufficient to add the dependency in the pom and save (cause when I save, eclipse builds the project)

Comment: @UtenteStack Create a Maven project in the Eclipse and add to the  `pom.xml` [Java Client For Google Maps Services](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.maps/google-maps-services/0.1.10). Don't install in the your local Maven repository anything!

Comment: How can I uninstall all the libraries that I have installed in my local repository? However that dependency is already in my pom

Comment: @UtenteStack You can just delete it (in your local repository), but, I think, you don't need to do it.

Comment: ok. Thank you. I won't delete them from my repo. Don't down vote my question, please :)

Comment: Maybe you'd like to gain further points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345170/why-do-i-get-incomplete-answers-using-google-maps-api-in-java