# Why do I get incomplete answers using google maps api in java?

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm using google maps API in java to check wether some places are correct, but I don't get all possible responses:

```
GeocodingApiRequest req = GeocodingApi.newRequest(context).address("Sydney");
try {
    GeocodingResult[] result = req.await();
    System.out.println("number of results: "+result.length);
    for(int i = 0;i < result.length;i++){
        System.out.println(result[i].formattedAddress);
        AddressComponent[] ac = result[i].addressComponents;
        for(AddressComponent acSingle : ac){
            System.out.println(acSingle.longName + " " + acSingle.shortName);
        }
    }
    // Handle successful request.
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle error
}
```

I get the following output:

```
number of results: 2
Sydney NSW, Australia
Sydney Sydney
New South Wales NSW
Australia AU
Sydney NSW, Australia
Sydney Sydney
New South Wales NSW
Australia AU
```

While, if you see what you can get by inserting the following url request, the results are many more:

[Sidney](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sidney)

In the link above, you can see that the results are many more than 2, indeed there is Sidney also in Ohio, for instance.

Comment: Try to ask at [http://gis.stackexchange.com/](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180443/why-do-i-get-incomplete-answers-using-google-maps-api-in-java

Comment: why dont you use javaScript? if you want i have wrote some javaScript for this problem.

Comment: I'm doing some test and I think Google has a threshold with some APIs Key and I coud not make it works with out key. try the follow and you are going to get two results:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=myKey&address=Sydney

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits?hl=es