# Why do I get always ZERO_RESULTS using post method (google-maps-api) in java with httpClient?

Tags: java, post, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following post method:

"myApiKey" stands for my google api key

```
public static void post(){
    try {
        Content resp = Request.Post("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json").bodyForm(Form.form().add("key",  "myApiKey").add("address",  "Sidney").build()).execute().returnContent();
        String response = resp.toString();
        System.out.println(response);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the method above, I have used fluent API([fluent API in the second grey box](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html))
The response is the following:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

@v.ladyev, I have already solved the problem of places containing spaces on my own with such preprocessing:

```
public static String preprocessLocation(String location){
    String[] locationSplitted = location.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    for(int j = 0; j < locationSplitted.length; j++){
        if(j != 0){
            query.append("+");
        }
        String[] parts = locationSplitted[j].split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
            query.append(parts[i]);
            if((i + 1) < parts.length){
                query.append("+");
            }
        }
        if((j + 1) < locationSplitted.length){
            query.append(",");
        }
    }
    return query.toString();
}
```

FOR THE ONES WHO WOULD LIKE TO APPEND OTHERS PARAMETERS or HEADERS (for instance, the key and the Accept-Language):

```
private static String post(String place){
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address",place));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", PUT_HERE_YOUR_KEY));
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json").setParameters(parameters);
            Content response = Request.Post(builder.build()).addHeader("Accept-Language", "en").execute().returnContent();
            return response.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What does the generated URL look like?  This works for me: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sidney

Comment: May be you shouldn't specify a fake API key.

Comment: @v.ladynev I have put my real API key in my code. I have just put that apikey in the code to publish here. I thought it was obvious. I have specified it editing my question now

Comment: @StackUser Your `preprocessLocation()` is incorrect, because of can be other non _alphanumeric characters_ in the geographic names, especially in other languages.

Comment: @v.ladynev: so, your URIBuilder encode the language characters different from alphanumeric?

Comment: @StackUser Yes. And, please, never use custom code for such tasks. It is very [hard to implement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16226168/3405171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some investigations.

Looks like, It is impossible to use a `POST` request with parameters in the request body with [*Geocoding API*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) (but it is need for [*Geolocation API*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro), for an example). *Geocoding API* waits parameters in the URL. So for empty URL's parameters it returns an empty response.

`Post` requests have a very useful feature — an encoding of request parameters can be specified. With `GET` requests we have opposite situation — it is need to encode request's parameters. Only *alphanumeric characters* don't need to be encoded — refer [Common pitfalls of URLs](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/#CommonpitfallsofURLs).

Based on this, @MiguelResendiz example will not always work. Consider the same,  but simplified method —  it is not need an API key for tests, and using `Request.Post` is the same as using `Request.Get` in this situation

```
private static void post(String address) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder http = new StringBuilder();
    http.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json");
    http.append("?");
    http.append("address=" + address);
    Content resp = Request.Post(http.toString()).execute().returnContent();
    System.out.println(resp);
}
```

It works for `post("Sidney")`.

But when we do `post("Red Light District")` we have an exception, because of the address has spaces

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 61`

To do encoding we can use [URIBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) from Apache HTTP Client. And to perform a valid get request

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
String address = "Red Light District";
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(url).setParameter("address", address);

Content response = Request.Get(builder.build()).execute().returnContent();

System.out.println(response);
```

It works pretty well.

Comment: I have voted up your answer. I'll have to read with more attention the first part of it

Comment: so, your URIBuilder encode the language character different from alphanumeric?

Comment: Great, I have forgotten possible spaces and I had focus on the problem described. This solve better the problem

Comment: @MiguelResendiz But the main problem is still unsolved. This kind of a request returns only two results.

Comment: @v.ladynev Google has some limitation when you have a free developer account. If you try to get this information without a key application you can get all the information if you use a free key application you are going to have a limit. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits?hl=es

Comment: @MiguelResendiz There is not such limit (only 2 addresses) by the link you provide .

Comment: @v.ladynev Main problem still unsolved with your post method? Sure? I get 5 results, using my api query with your method, if I look for Sidney

Comment: @StackUser May be I was wrong...Can't check it now :)

Comment: @StackUser did you solve your problem? I did not have any other clue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, bodyForm() is not adding your parameters and I could not found any kind of documentation.

```
public static void post(){
        try {
            StringBuilder http = new StringBuilder();
            http.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json");
            http.append("?");
            http.append("key=myAppKey");
            http.append("&");
            http.append("address=Sidney");
            Request maps = Request.Post(http.toString());
            System.out.println(maps.toString());
            Response mapsResponse = maps.execute();
            Content resp = mapsResponse.returnContent();
            String response = resp.toString();
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your method seems to work and returns json correctly!

Try also reply this, if you can:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345170/why-do-i-get-incomplete-answers-using-google-maps-api-in-java

I have voted up your question and I'm planning to elege it as best one

Comment: ` bodyForm()` adds parameters, but other way. Your answer has [some problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35366739/3405171), but  anyway I up vote it.